# How to log all DDLs on a gcloud SQL instance?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I would like to log all DDL queries that are run on SQL instance. I tried looking into plugins but they are not allowed.

Edit: It's a MySQL instance.

Comment: This is supported now. See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/use-db-audit. It does use a plugin under the hood, though, but it's a plugin created by Google, which, if you're already trusting Google Cloud, seems trustworthy to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the Cloud SQL Flag "log_statement" to value "mod" to log all Data definition language (DDL) statements.

The reference link :
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#postgres-l

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention its a MySQL instance. Is there something similar for it?

Comment: Will this work for you (enabling binary logs in MySQL) -
"gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --enable-bin-log". Reference : https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/pitr#enablingpitr

Comment: Unfortunately not. Binary log is row based which means all transactions are in binary format and hence unreadable. I guess DML audit log is supported only by Postgres for now. Thanks for the info though.